# Regex - date format not using mixed seperators

Tags: regex

I've written a regex that identifies dates in the form of dd/mm/yyyy or dd.mm.yyyy but it currently accepts dd/mm.yyyy as a correct format but I don't want mixed separators to be accepted as valid. How would I modify my regex to fix this issue.

My Regex is:

```
^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[/|./.](0[1-9]|1[012])[/./.](19|20)\d\d$
```

Comment: You would have to make separate *or* `|` branches for each case like that. `dd\/mm\/yyyy|dd\.mm\.yyyy`

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/qg9Rzf/2

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Use a look-ahead to require that the same separators is used:

```
^(?=.*([/.]).*\1)<your regex here>$
```

The expression `(?=.*([/.]).*\1)` is a look ahead that contains a back reference `\1` to the first separator `[/.]`, meaning it must be repeated later in the input.

The whole regex would be (simplifying the separator expression to just `[/.]`):

```
^(?=.*([/.]).*\1)(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[/.](0[1-9]|1[012])[/.](19|20)\d\d$
```

Comment: That's not going to work. The backreference would only work if you actually capture `[/.]`, at which point it'd be easier to drop the lookahead. Or, you can put an alternation in your lookahead if you want to avoid an additional capture.

Comment: @hvd oops! Nice catch. fixed.

Comment: To clarify what I meant: `^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])([/.])(0[1-9]|1[012])\2(19|20)\d\d$` still seems simpler to me, but with your edit, your answer should work. Of course assuming the OP's choice of regex engine supports these features.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
^(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(\/|\.)(?:0[1-9]|1[012])\1(19|20)\d\d$
```

This will match

> 01/02/2018

or

> 01.02.2018

But will not match

> 01/02.2018

`\1` matches same contents in the first bracket which is `(\/|\.)` in this case. This is called "back reference". So the second separator have to be the repeat of what's matching in the first bracket.

By using `(?:)` instead normal `()` it will prevent the bracket to be counted as matching patterns for back reference, it will make it easier to code, and this is better for performance too, because anything in normal bracket will be stored in the memory to be prepared for back reference. So you should use `(?:)` if you are using brackets just to cover patterns.

Comment: Good one. How i missed `\1`?

Answer (score 1):

Solution for **PHP** and **Python**.

**Regex**: [`^(?:[0-2][0-9]|3[01])(?:(\/)|\.)(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])(?(1)\/|\.)(?:19|20)\d{2}$`](https://regex101.com/r/qg9Rzf/4)

**Details**:

- `(?:)` Non capturing group
- `()` Capturing group
- `[]` Match a single character present in the list
- `|` Or
- `(?(1))` If Clause, Group 1.

**Output**:

```
01/12/1999 true
25.12.1999 true
23.12/1999 false
23/12.1999 false
23,12/1999 false
```